Making subscriptions sync
I'm working on a project for my company and deeply respecting the NDA that I have signed I provide the following code snippet without any sensitive information, consider this code:


toggleLoadingAnimation()
Subscription1()
Subscription2()
…
Subscription10()

toggleLoadingAnimation()
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>



The problem is that all the Subscription methods are async, they all look like that:
this.randomFieldSubscription = this.randomService.randomEntityList.value$.subscribe(entityList => {this.entityList = entityList})
When the .subscribe gets executed we also send a request to the server inside the randomService.
How do I make the second toggleLoadingAnimation() get executed only when all the previous Subscriptions are done and all responses from the server are recieved?

You can refer to the forkJoin method from RxJS and do something like this :
First make sur to transform your Observable into Promise with firstValueFrom
toggleLoadingAnimationPromise() {
    return firstValueFrom(this.randomService.randomEntityList());
  }

Subscription1Promise() {
    return firstValueFrom(this.randomService.Subscription1());
  }

forkJoin({
      toggleLoadingAnimation: this.toggleLoadingAnimationPromise(),
      Subscription1: this.Subscription1Promise(),
      Subscription2: this.Subscription2Promise(),
    }).subscribe(({ toggleLoadingAnimation, Subscription1, Subscription2 }) => {
      //your code logic here
      //...
      //your call
      toggleLoadingAnimationPromise().then((data)=>{
       //your code logic
      })
    })
  }

